# This python selenium program does not iterate

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to iterate the function using a while loop, but it iterates only once, and after that, the program just stands still.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Process


def browse(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.__exit__()

Pros = []
urls = open('urls.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        for url_item in urls:
            print(url_item)
            p = Process(target=browse, args=(url_item,))
            Pros.append(p)
            p.start()
        for t in Pros:
            t.join()
```

Comment: You are not reading anything from the urls.txt file you're opening, so I don't think the variable `urls` gets populated properly.

Comment: You're appending to Pros array in every iteration, but you're not clearing it before the next step. That might be the problem. Try setting it (`Pros = []`) inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem relies on how the file's content was read as well as how the Process object has been started. It starting on a temporary Process object instead of the Process object in process list (Pros).
In short, it is only a referencing issue and wrong way of utlizing File Object.
Here is the working code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Process


def browse(URL):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(URL)
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.__exit__()

Pros = []
urls = open('urls.txt').readlines()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("testing")
        for url_item in urls:
            print(url_item)
            p = Process(target=browse, args=(url_item,))
            Pros.append(p)
            Pros[-1].start()
        for t in Pros:
            t.join()
        Pros = []
```

Comment: It's not working. If I use the above code, the multithreading will not work as intended. It runs the code one by one instead of running parallelly.

Comment: I just noticed, i have edited the answer, you can try it out again.

Comment: No, you can check from your side as well.

Comment: From my side, the process actually prints out the page_source fine. After edit, it prints all the page source simultaneously as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the error is about? Show the traceback from the console when the program is running.

Comment: Yes, but it prints only once and it's not iterating the loop.

Comment: I found the error. It was due to how you are utilizing the file object. I have edited the answer to the correct fix. Try again, it should work this time.